# How to automatically update or compress a CSS, JS and HTML file every time I save its "source file" in Vim?

Tags: html, css, compression, javascript, minimize

I wanted to minimize or compress CSS, Javascript and maybe Html files like Google does. Because, I used Google's Page-Speed and it recommended me to compress files. It provides me the compressed versions but I would like to do this automatically.I don't want to deal with 2 files every time I want to edit something. So basically, I want to have 2 files in a folder, for instance, **style.src.css**
and **style.css**.

I want to know how to do the following:

1. Update the ouput file everytime I edit the input file.
2. A command that automatically compress CSS, Html, and Javascript files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to have vim do that.  A bit of reading on the vim autoscripts ( http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html ) would be helpful, but here's a decent guess:

```
au BufWritePost *.html !zip %.zip %
```

In .vimrc

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `gzip`, not `zip`.

Answer (score 0):

[YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) isn't VIM and is usually done manually, at build time, but you can instantiate YUI Compressor on-the-fly to handle minification on your server (requires Java).

Note that YUI Compressor *minifies* JS and CSS (not HTML). [Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_compression) can also be done on the server, reducing file sizes even more.